# Меня кто-то накрутил?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Что-то захожу и вижу новую привилегию за 20к репы.
И думаю, "за что?". Далее смотрю на репу и у меня 22к+, хотя минуту назад было 14к.

Что это?

Вроде в истории не вижу никакой резкой накрутки.

Или это даётся за какие-то заслуги?