# Самый большой плюс репутации за всю историю

Tags: обсуждение

Интересно, какой самый большой плюс репутации за всю историю? +10000? И действует ли ограничение репутации в день? Я имею ввиду только ruSo.

Comment: ограничение действует только на голоса. Репутация за принятые ответы и конкурсы могут превышать

Comment: @Grundy понятно!

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9760/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb

Comment: 8k?????????????

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica наверное...